# regular payments formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Jill has received $175000. She is going to deposit this into an account with an annual interest rate of 12% where the interest is compounded semi annually. She will make equal withdrawals every six months. Find the size of the withdrawal so that all money has been withdrawn after 8 years.

I know the formula for compound interest but how I would do this question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the semiannual withdrawal. The present value of the $T=16$ semiannual withdrawals must equal the initial capital $C =175,000$. Using the semiannual rate $i = \sqrt{1.12}-1$ (please check if this what you mean by "compounded semi-annually"), you find the equality
$$C = \sum_{t=1}^{T} R (1+i)^{-t}$$
Solving for $R$ yields
$$R = \frac{Ci}{1 - (1+i)^{-T}}$$
(The last step requires computing the sum of a geometric progression.)

Comment: I don't understand your formula for i ? Isn't i = 0.12

Comment: Your question says that 0.12 is the annual interest rate. Since interest is compounded semi-annually, you need the semi-annual interest rate for the formula to apply.

Comment: Normally $12\%$ annual interest compounded semi-annually means $6\%$ is paid twice a year, resulting in an effective annual interest of $1.06^2-1 =12.36\%$  The $i$ in the formula should then be $0.06$

Comment: There are different conventions around the world, and I am not sure which one was implicitly meant. Ross Millikan's suggestion makes sense. (Instead, I assumed that the semi-annually compounded interest rate was meant to yield an effective annual interest of 1.12.)